# Android studio v. 3.0.1 Error:Already seen doctype

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I only use Psiphon to connect to the Internet. Since I have updated android studio to version 3, I am facing the following gradle sync error:

> Error: Already seen doctype.

Comment: Uninstall the program and all related (SDK) folders and install the latest stable android studio version again.

Comment: Try connecting using a vpn connection and not Psiphon. Maybe it works. I get that error on some machines as well sometimes. All I know is it has something to do with connection proxy

Comment: Also I solved the issue by re-installing Android Studio

Comment: Mee too i reinstall android studio

Comment: Make sure you have HTTP and HTTPS proxy port and host settings on the gradle.properties file.

Comment: I have uninstalled and reconfigured my `android studio`. It didn't help. Just make sure your connection is stable. Also, check `gradle.properties` configuration unless you do not use VPN connection.

Answer (score 2):

When sync is starting, Android Studio shows the Proxy Settings. Check "Enable HTTPS Proxy" and set "Host name" and "Port name" similar to HTTP Proxy settings.

[image: Android Studio Proxy Settings]

NOTE: 5100 is my own proxy port, use your proxy port number instead.

Don't forget to set proxy settings of Android Studio as following:

[image: Http Proxy settings]

Comment: Agha merci , be ghole stackia You saved my life :)))

Answer (score 1):

this error is for download Necessary files From Google Servers
use Right VPN Connection Such As Cisco Any Connect